# C# .Net.Sockets Onreceive partially works

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert C# source I used in Unity to a Visual Studio Windows forms app and I can't figure out why my onreceive part won't work.

What I'm doing is making a TCP connection to the server (works) then my server sends a welcome package that I do receive but can't handle.

Sometimes it does run completely but does not trigger the trigger (explained later).

Since the source is originally from a unity project there I can wait for the update and I think that is why it works in there.

The code:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int byteAmt = myStream.EndRead(ar);
            byte[] myBytes = new byte[byteAmt];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(asyncBuff, 0, myBytes, 0, byteAmt);
            if (byteAmt == 0) return;

            //UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
            //{
            ClientHandleData.HandleData(myBytes);
            //});

            myStream.BeginRead(asyncBuff, 0, 8192, OnReceive, null);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("we have an error in onreceive");
        }
    }
```

the Handledata

```
public static void HandleData(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] Buffer;
        Buffer = (byte[])data.Clone();

        if (playerBuffer == null) playerBuffer = new ByteBuffer();
        playerBuffer.WriteBytes(Buffer);

        if (playerBuffer.Count() == 0)
        {
            playerBuffer.Clear();
            return;
        }

        if (playerBuffer.Length() >= 8)
        {
            pLength = playerBuffer.ReadLong(false);
            if (pLength <= 0)
            {
                playerBuffer.Clear();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (playerBuffer.Length() >= 8)
        {
            pLength = playerBuffer.ReadLong(false);
            if (pLength <= 0)
            {
                playerBuffer.Clear();
                return;
            }
        }

        while (pLength > 0 & pLength <= playerBuffer.Length() - 8)
        {
            if (pLength <= playerBuffer.Length() - 8)
            {
                playerBuffer.ReadLong();
                data = playerBuffer.ReadBytes((int)pLength);
                HandleDataPackets(data);
            }
            pLength = 0;

            if (playerBuffer.Length() >= 8)
            {
                pLength = playerBuffer.ReadLong(false);
                if (pLength < 0)
                {
                    playerBuffer.Clear();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and last the HandleDataPackets

```
public static void HandleDataPackets(byte[] data)
    {
        long packetnum; ByteBuffer buffer; Packet_ packet;
        buffer = new ByteBuffer();
        buffer.WriteBytes(data);
        packetnum = buffer.ReadLong();
        buffer = null;

        Form1.label1.Text = "reading packetnum";
        if (packetnum == 0) return;

        Form1.label1.Text = "packetnum read and is not 0";

        if (packets.TryGetValue(packetnum, out packet))
        {
            Form1.label1.Text = "trigger";
            packet.Invoke(data);
        }
    }
```

sometimes it runs all the way to the Form1.label1.Text = "packetnum read and is not 0"; line in HandleDataPacket but then it does not trigger the trigger line :(.

Can someone please tell me why this is?

Comment: I've removed your extra tag for you. From the `visual-studio` tag wiki: Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question.

Comment: Unless you haven't provided some code, you never add anything to packets.

Comment: that would be the server who sends a welcome message.
`code`public static void SendWelcomeMessage(long index)
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer();
            buffer.WriteLong((long)ServerPackets.SWelcome);
            Console.WriteLine("sending welcome package.");
            buffer.WriteString("Welcome! Please log in and enjoy the game.");
            SendDataTo(index, buffer.ToArray());
        }

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem.
I was trying to initialize the packages in the unity way but had to trigger it from the program itself.

i created a Networkmanager class that initializes the different packages and then makes the connection. this fixed it!

all code above is working as intended.

Just realized that john was telling me this!..
To bad i did not see that a few hours ago.
Post it as an answer and ill mark it like one.